# Using GridsearchCV () with holdout validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, hyperparameters

GridsearchCV () has an argument cv whose value by default is 3 means that it is 3fold. Is there any way to use Gridsearch() with a holdout validation scheme. For example 80-20% split???

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit` or `sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit` with `n_splits=1` in place of cv argument

Read the documentation for more details
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit